# Determine the set of complex numbers $z$ such that $z^6$ is a negative real

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

I want to solve it using the trigonometric (and not the polar) form of complex numbers.

Let $z^6=-a$, being $a$ a positive real number.

$|-a|=a$ and the $-a$ argument is $π$ because $-a$ is a negative real number.

Then the six roots of $-a$ are:

$z_0=(a)^{1/6}(\cos(π/6)+i\sin(π/6))$

$z_1=(a)^{1/6}(\cos(π/2)+i\sin(π/2))$

$z_2=(a)^{1/6}(\cos(7π/6)+i\sin(7π/6))$

$z_3=(a)^{1/6}(\cos(3π/2)+i\sin(3π/2))$

$z_4=(a)^{1/6}(\cos(11π/6)+i\sin(11π/6))$

$z_5=(a)^{1/6}(\cos(5π/6)+i\sin(5π/6))$

These complex numbers $z_i$ with $0≤i<6$ ($i$ is a natural number) satisfy $z^6$ is a negative real number but these complex numbers are infinite because they depend from $a$ and $a$ is any positive real number, that is, the values they can take are infinite so how do I specify the set of complex numbers requested?

Comment: Your answer is fine. You could write it as $\{ r z_k | r \ge 0, \text{ where } z_1,...z_6 \text{ are as above} \}$, where the $z_k$ are as above with $a=1$. There is no need to retain the $a^6$ part, as $a$ is arbitrary.

Comment: You got infinitely many numbers because there are infinitely many possible negative reals you could get as a result of raising said number to the sixth power. For each $a$ there are six complex sixth roots. For infinitely many different $a$, ...

Comment: perfect, thank you very much! @copper.hat

Comment: Note that some of your $z_k$ expressions are wrong. You have $z_5=z_1$. You messed the $5\pi/6$ term

Comment: You say that for every posible possitive real $a$ there are $6$ possible complex sixth roots of $-a$.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigonometric and not polar"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going backwards; the direct approach is easier.

If you write $z=a(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)$, then
$$
z^6=a^6(\cos6\alpha+i\sin6\alpha)
$$
(De Moivre), which is a negative real if and only if $\sin6\alpha=0$ and $\cos6\alpha<0$.

Can you go on? Yes, $a$ can be any positive real, but $\alpha$ is restricted.

Comment: Thanks for answering! You put $\sin6\alpha=0$ for the imaginary part to be canceled, right? And said the restrictions that you put the exercise would be shown? @egreg

Comment: If $\cos 6\alpha=-1$, then automatically $\sin 6\alpha=0$.

Comment: @Ayesca Yes, that's the idea: together with $\cos6\alpha<0$, this forces $6\alpha=\pi+2k\pi$, with $0\le k\le 5$. Not much different from your approach, but cleaner.

Comment: @Andrei Yes, of course; but the condition that $z^6$ is real is equivalent to $\sin6\alpha=0$.

Comment: @egreg thank you very much, I will solve it in this way, it is true that it is cleaner